# What does a/.b[c][[1]] mean?

Tags: functions

The function b[c_] has been previously defined. Does that "1" refer to the smallest number of a list?

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/193

Comment: Actually, "1" refers to the first element of a list, **not** the smallest number of a list. Thus `a[[1]]` is the same as `First[a]`.

Answer (score 7):

If you just want to know what the double brackets mean, you can highlight them and use help. Or, you can use Information (?), for example:

```
?[[
```

[image]

Or, you can use [`Hold`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hold) with [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) to figure out what it means:

```
a /. b[c][[1]] //Hold //FullForm
```

> Hold[ReplaceAll[a,Part[b[c],1]]]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 1 refers to the first element of the list.  "/." is a rule replacement so I presume in this case that function "b" is returning a list of rules, which the line of code intends to use as a replacement operator for a.

Starting list or array notation at "1" is sometimes confusing for people used to "c" starting indices at 0.  Note that there is a form of "Mod" that will properly provide the right index so you don't end up with "0" when you try to get a part of a list.